# Why can't I use a constexpr data member pointer as a template argument in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

Please consider the following code:

```
template <typename T, typename P, T P:: *s> struct H {};

struct AA { int i; };

int main()
{
  typedef int AA::*PI;
  constexpr PI pi = &AA::i;

  H<int, AA, &AA::i> h1;    // OK
  // H<int, AA, pi> h2;     // compile error
}
```

I have member pointer `pi` pointing to `AA::i`.
`pi` is a `constexpr` variable. Why can't I use it as a template parameter, even though using `&AA::i` directly works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because those are the rules, at least in C++11; 14.3.2/1 only allows "a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1", which describes the `&AA::i` syntax.

This has changed in the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), and now the requirement for any type is just "a converted constant expression of
the type of the template-parameter", under which your code would be fine.

I don't know whether or not this change is in C++14, since I don't yet have access to that published standard.

Comment: The DIS for C++14 is N4141 I think, which you can check out from GitHub yourself.

Comment: That said, I compared the two and indeed the change was only applied *after* C++14.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere answer!